# Is there a way to identify prominent increases and decreases of a line?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy

Im wondering if there is a way in Python to identify prominent increases and decreases in a dataset that forms a line? By prominent, I mean "significant" or "extraordinary" compared to previous changes (x - x(i)).

In reference to the graph below, I'm searching for a method to identify the "extraordinary" changes in x-x(i) such as seen in between period 60 and 65.

Edit: Period 30-50 would also be considered "extraordinary" and above was just meant to be an example.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl
import numpy as np

    #create random numbers 
        x = np.linspace(1, 80)
        def f(x):
            y = 0
            result = []
            for _ in x:
                result.append(y)
                y += np.random.normal(scale=2)
            return np.array(result)
        
        def runningMean(x, N):
            return np.convolve(x, np.ones((N,))/N)[(N-1):]
        
        pl.plot(x, runningMean(f(x), 80))
```

[image]

Comment: Not clear what the code is intended to do and what exactly is problem statement?

Comment: I mean, I would consider 30-50 to be prominent as well. This is fairly arbitrary

Comment: I agree @d_kennetz, it was meant to serve as an example. Sorry for being unclear! :)

Comment: @ipj The code is just meant to show how I generate my data. The issue im struggling to overcome is how to identify prominent increases/decreases in noisy datasets . I've previously triend to use the IQR of the absolute differences and the 75th percentile as a benchmark but im thinking there must be a more efficent and accurate way to find this out.

Comment: Please define what you mean by:  "significant", "extraordinary"

Comment: I think you need to start by asking yourself what makes those changes prominent.  For instance, they could be prominent because the value are significantly outside the long-term mean of the data set.  Or, they could be prominent because the slope (rate of change) is large before and after.  A clear definition of 'prominent' will make a detection algorithm much easier to figure out.

Comment: What physical process generates the data? Maybe we need some domain knowledge to guess how an extraordinary change may be defined.

Comment: You could investigate using something like [MACD](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/m/macd.asp).

Comment: @zabop By significant, I mean where the rate of change between the differences (x-x(i)) results in a much "steeper" line in comparison to the other differences.

Comment: @ChrisMueller Thanks for your valuable input. In the case of my data, it is most likely be "steeper" because the ROC is larger compared to the other differences and therefore makes the line "steeper". Thanks again for your input! :)

Comment: @quizzical_panini Thanks for your input. However, the MACD would compare the differences between two moving averages and does not really tell me too much about the steepness of the line. Thank you though :)

Comment: Ok, then please define mathematically, what is 'much "steeper"'.

Answer (score 1):

I don't get why do you generate your signal, the way you generate it, and also your code is not reproducible, in the sense that you don't specify seed. In any case, in general having a `signal` you can do it by testing:

```
np.abs(np.diff(signal))
```

e.g. against some threshold in periods of time. It is equivalent to testing the absolute value of x[i] - x[i+1] you are interested in or the absolute value of derivative (for a rescaled threshold).
Thus, in your case you could do:

```
signal = runningMean(f(x), 80)
abs_diff = np.abs(np.diff(signal))
pl.plot(x, signal)
pl.plot(x[:-1], abs_diff)
```

to see how does the `diff` behave and to assess what would you count as "extraordinary". Then identify when does `abs_diff` go sufficiently high and for sufficiently long to satisfy what you call "extraordinary".

Comment: Hi! Sorry for my late reply. I figured a similar approach would be likewise the one you provided in your reply. Thank you for taking the time responding and your help